# Android apk file Dynamic Build

Tags: android, build, runtime, apk

I am working on an android project which requires me to build the android's apk file at run time, i am doing so because i need to add a text document. This is like a client server process.

When a user opens a particular ip address,  at run time on server side the apk file is built with the text document. The text document contains the users master data which is unique to a single user. At the end, the android app is directly downloaded and installed on mobile phone.

If any one knows the way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do at least several things (I've done similar task in J2ME):

1. You have to have JDK on server side
2. ANT tool installed there
3. Some scripting tool to generate sources (as a last resort your own Java servlet)

So based on user response you should:

- using scripting tool generate Java source
- generate/collect necessary resources
- generate AndroidManifest.xml
- run on top of that ANT builder
- get APK file and upload it to customer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can see would be to use some software like maven to build your project dynamically. This way, when you receive a request from a user, you start a build with maven and push the output to the request.
There are some nice projects of integration Android - Maven like [this](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).